# Find expected value of unique types given different numbers of items in each type

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, balls-in-bins

I'm working on a practice problem for an exam and I haven't been able to find out a way to solve this. There are 4 bins that contain different amounts of different colored balls. I.e. 1 red, 1 green, 2 yellow, 6 blue. Draw 3 balls randomly without replacement. Let the r.v. Y represent the number of different types of balls in the selection. Find the expectation of Y. I've tried using indicators variables to represent the number of unique colors drawn, but I'm not able to get any farther. How would this be solved?

Comment: "Draw 3 balls randomly." With or without replacement?

Comment: @user51547 edited to without replacement

Comment: Where did you get stuck on the indicator approach? I think it should work.

Comment: I created an indicator function I j s.t. for each color we define the indicator variable to be 1 if we draw at least one ball from the jth color. However, this didn't really work out because the amount of balls aren't the same. I'm just not really sure how to set this problem up.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer.**

This is a long-winded comment.

First see [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), which contains a proof that the formula applies even when the events are dependent.

Assume that $(a,b,c,d)$ represent the number of Color-1, ..., Color-4, respectively.

The probability of drawing $3$ balls that do not contain (for example) Color-1 is

$$Q_1 = \frac{\binom{b+c+d}{3}}{\binom{a+b+c+d}{3}}.$$

I could be mistaken, because my knowledge of Linearity of Expectation is somewhat superficial.  To the best of my knowledge, the desired computation is

$$\sum_{i=1}^4 P_i ~: ~P_i = 1 - Q_i.$$

Alternatively:

$$4 - \sum_{i=1}^4 Q_i.$$